# Finding the count of a specific string in a list that contains a dictionary

Tags: json, python-3.x

I would like to loop through this list and find how many times the phrase 'Client_id_new' appears and output that number to a variable. This is a snippet of data I receive on return and it is converted into a json.loads and I want to find how many iterations there are of 'Client_id_new', there can be more than two... The end goal is to take those iterations and assign them to their own variables. Each Key will be the same however, every value will be different.

In short: I am trying to count how many there are as that can range from 1 to many. Once I find out how many there are I imagine I can loop through the dictionary and assign the key values based on indices with another for loop?

```
[{'client_id_new': 'client key 1'}, {'client_id_new': 'client key 2'}]
```

Comment: `sum('client_id_new' in d for d in my_list)`

Comment: What would the for loop look like to loop through the list and assign the dictionary values to their respective variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
data = [{'client_id_new': 'client key 1'}, {'client_id_new': 'client key 2'}]
answer = sum('client_id_new' in d for d in data)
print(f"client_id_new appears {answer} times in the data")
```

The output is:

```
client_id_new appears 2 times in the data
```